# Java find Object which not containing in List of object

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I wondering is there any way to filter object array with another object array. Its is to hard to explain but ill try my best

this is my first entity

```
public class MDynamicFieldTypes implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private TDynamicFieldCategories category;
    private String icon;
    private String code;
    private String text;

}
```

this is second entity

```
public class DynamicFields implements Serializable {

    private Long id;
    private Instant createdDate;
    private Instant lastModifiedDate;
    private String value;
    private UserProfile createdByUser;
    private UserProfile lastModifiedByUser;
    private Project project;
    private EntityProfile entityProfile;
    private UserProfile userProfile;
    private MDynamicFieldTypes type;
  
}
```

i have two list of this each entities
Like this

```
List<MDynamicFieldTypes> dynamicFieldTypes;
List<DynamicFields> dynamicFields;
```

And I need to get MDynamicFieldTypes list which not containing in dynamicFields->type List and add fake object to which not containing in the dynamicFields List

as the example

First list like this

```
List<MDynamicFieldTypes> dynamicFieldTypes = [{id=1,category="A",code=a1,text="ccc"},
{id=2,category="B",code=a2,text="bbbb"},
{id=3,category="C",code=a3,text="cccc"},
{id=4,category="C",code=a4,text="cccc"},
];
```

Second one like this

```
List<DynamicFields> dynamicFields=[{id=1,value="xxx",type={id=1,category="A",code=a1,text=b},{id=2,value="yyy";type={id=3,category="C",code=a3,text=b},];
```

i need get as the result following List

```
List <MDynamicFieldTypes> notContaing =[{id=2,category="B",code=a2,text="bbbb"},{id=4,category="C",code=a4,text="cccc"}];
```

Comment: can you show some example with the expected output?

Comment: @Deadpool I have changed question please take look

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a two step solution

First create a set of all existing types in the `dynamicFields` list

```
Set<MDynamicFieldTypes> existing = dynamicFields.stream().map( f -> { return f.type; } ).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Then use that set to filter out any non-existing type in the `dynamicFieldTypes` list

```
List<MDynamicFieldTypes> missing = dynamicFieldTypes.stream().filter( type -> { 
  return !existing.contains(type);
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @BuddhikaPrasadh `existing` is not a keyword, it's a variable. See the first line of code

Comment: It's hard to improve anything from an anonymous, uncommented down vote.